# Some useful functions of MySQL Workbench for SQL Server management studio

Tags: ssms, mysql-workbench

Our project is moving from MySQL to MS SQL and after a long time working with MySQL Workbench I really miss some features in SQL Server Management studio (2014).
Do you know whether they exist in SSMS or there is an alternative/replacement application for SSMS to work with database?
Functions are listed below:

1. Generate update data script to review and to be able to copy-paste it. Do not update data when I move to another row when the table is opened for editing.
   Some changes are still made in database in our project, and sometimes it's easier to add some rows manually in 5 tables, get the script, test it and run the script at production environment. I don't want to write a script for each update and I don't want to make a mistake when copying data to production server using edit table option.
2. Review update table script BEFORE the changes were made, not after (I am talking about Tools - Options - Designer - Auto generate change scripts).
3. Upload a file using select file dialog into a binary field.
   Again, I know about using OPENROWSET function, just interested how to do it as I used to.
4. Ability to view large text fields in a convenient way in SSMS. Now I have to copy data from a field and paste it into notepad. (For example, error message with a long trace log)
5. Save a few tabs with some useful scripts and open all of them when I open SSMS.
6. Is there any way to organize tabs to be able to work with 10+ tabs more effectively? Now only 6 of them can be shown on the screen (compate it to 15 tabs in MySQL WB).
7. Simple 'search field' (like Ctrl+F in Excel) to be able to search data in all fields displayed on the screen.

I would appreciate any ideas.

Thank you.